# Emacs outline-mode custom heading and space between headers

Tags: regular-expressions, outline-mode

I'm trying to define a structure for outline-minor-mode so I can organize my init.el conf without relying in org.

So far I could not get to work with two levels of heading, I would like to have ;;; and ;;;; as possible levels, so I could organize a little further.

My code so far:

```
;;; Outline-mode
;; Local Variables:
;; outline-regexp: ";\\{3,4\\} "
;; outline-heading-alist: ((";;; " . 1) (";;;; " . 2))
;; eval: (outline-minor-mode 1)
;; eval: (while (re-search-forward outline-regexp nil t) (outline-hide-subtree))
;; End:
```

I'm not very good at regex yet, so I'm not sure how to make it to work.

The problem is that without two levels of heading when I "hide all" the levels they got without any space or further organization like in the left image. I can try to break some lines like in the right image, but when I show/hide again the folding ignore the lines again.

I'm trying to avoid outshine and org, but I might migrate if I can't manage to accomplish the following:

[image: Space problems]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure if I understand your question, but you may want to try setting `(setq outline-blank-line t)`.

Non-nil means to leave unhidden blank line before heading.

Comment: And that's it. :) I can't upvote you because of the weird reputation policies of stack. Thank you very much!